# HTML5 Canvas & Processor friendly - How can I create this fill / mask?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, vector-graphics

**Scenario**

In this interactive, let's say the user clicks in four places on a canvas. I want my fill to follow the exact order of clicks. *Please consider my "demonstration" below*

[image]

The GREEN line shows the fill area I'm going for (the red is min bounding box and can be safely ignored).

I need to clip/mask the area otherwise I would use a stroke (easy). I have yet to find a processor friendly way to convert a stroke to a fill or I would use that (this has to be usable on mobile devices).

**Question**

How can I programmatically generate the green bounding path (fill) for these click points? I have all the coordinate (`mouseevent`s) in an `array` to loop through.

**Code**

Here's the simplified stroke equivalent of what I'm trying to accomplish ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d839e347/))

```
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.moveTo(40, 40);
ctx.lineTo(180, 40);
ctx.lineTo(40, 180);
ctx.lineTo(180, 180);
ctx.lineWidth = 40;
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Are you after a mask (as in a bitmap) or a path (a set of 2D coordinates and connecting lines)?

Comment: Ideally I would have an array of 2d coordinates I can use to create a path from (usable with `ctx.fill()` and `ctx.clip()`).

Comment: That is a complex bit of code. For each line segment, add two half circles (radius path width /2) at the ends and connect with line segments to make a pill like shape along line. Then for each shape find all the intercept points with all the other shapes. Then for each intercept point remove all that are inside any pill shape. Weld all points closer than pixel. The result,  2D points and connecting line segments and arcs. Find top most and follow making path clockwise till back to start. If any points remain repeat but anticlockwise until no more points. That will create the paths you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been working on this all day. Here's what I came up with:

Most important piece:

You HAVE to know the current orientation / direction of the cursor before you can save a point to the array. This is crucial and if you mess this up you will get a path that collapses on itself.

Here's code for that:

```
    var radians = null;
    var x2 = lastMouseEvent.clientX,
        x1 = currentMouseEvent.clientX,
        y2 = lastMouseEvent.clientY,
        y1 = currentMouseEvent.clientY

    radians = Math.atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2) * -1 // you can remove the -1 if everything is backwards for your app
```

- collect all mouse coords in an array, store the current radians (inside/outside) too
- loop through array drawing a line for the INSIDE of the path, factor in orientation of the pointer
- reverse array to start drawing outside of path
- connect last point from INSIDE track to first point of OUTSIDE track
- loop through the array again, drawing a line for the OUTSIDE of the path, factor in orientation of the pointer
- connect last point from OUTSIDE track to first point of INSIDE track

*If you don't make sure all your points connect, you won't get a complete path and this won't work*

Here's how you can factor in orientation, depending on track:

```
var radians = [orientation radians stored in your array]
var diameter = [diameter you want your path to be]

var inside = {
    x: Math.sin(radians) * (diameter / 2),
    y: Math.cos(radians) * (diameter / 2)
}
var outside = {
    x: Math.sin(radians) * (diameter / -2),
    y: Math.cos(radians) * (diameter / -2)
}
```

And all you do is add x/y values from your respect track to the coordinates you're currently looping through.

Yes, this is a pain in the ass, but the performance is great on all devices. GL HF